# density function and expected value of binomial-like distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution, density-function

Suppose a computer needs 20 memory chips to work, and there is a 0.1 probability that a given chip is defective.

Part 1:  If $X$ denotes the number of chips to be ordered to ensure that 20 chips work, what is the probability density function of the random variable $X$?

Part 2:  What is the expected value of that density function?

My attempt:  In my opinion, the problem wasn't worded as clearly as it could have been.  I interpreted Part 1 to ask for the density function $f(x)$, where $f(x)$ is the probability that exactly 20 of the $x$ chips work.  Under this interpretation, I previously thought the density function should be $f(x)={x \choose 20}0.9^{20}0.1^{x-20}$.  However, this density function does not appear to sum to one.  I've tried numerous other potential density functions, and I can't seem to find one that sums to one.  I would greatly appreciate any advice on this.

Comment: A quick comment: it's a good sanity check to verify that a probability density/mass function does sum to one. Does yours?

Comment: Apparently not.  Thanks for catching that!  But now, being as this is the fifth density function I've tried, I'm at a bit of a loss for what the density function should actually be.  Do you have any advice?

Comment: Take it with a grain of salt (it's late here), but you may want to look into the negative binomial distribution.

Comment: Wow, it's been so long since I've had a probability course (I'm just trying to brush up now for grad school) that I completely forgot about the negative binomial distribution.  I really think that should be the one that does it.  Thanks so much!  It's just strange that, in the book I'm using, the negative binomial dist. isn't mentioned until the chapter after this problem.  It makes me wonder if the problem was put into the wrong chapter by mistake.

Comment: *Pedantically:* it should be noted that $X$ does not have a probability *density* function at all, because it is a *discrete-valued* random variable.  Rather, it has a probability *mass* function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer to the first part is not correct, because if we conceptualize the ordering process as comprising successive orders of one chip at a time until the $20^{\rm th}$ non-defective chip is obtained, then we stop precisely when that $20^{\rm th}$ good chip is obtained, hence the last ordered chip is always good.  Consequently, there are only $\binom{x-1}{19}$ ways of arranging the previous $19$ good chips among the $x-1$ previous chips ordered before the last good one is obtained, hence $$\Pr[X = x] = \binom{x-1}{19} (0.9)^{20} (0.1)^{x-20}, \quad x = 20, 21, 22, \ldots.$$  This is a **negative binomial** distribution with parameters $r = 20$ and $p = 0.9$.

To find $\operatorname{E}[X]$, it suffices to observe by construction that $$\sum_{x=r}^\infty \Pr[X = x] = \sum_{x=r}^\infty \binom{x-1}{r-1} p^r (1-p)^{x-r} = 1.$$  Next, consider $$x \binom{x-1}{r-1} = \frac{x!}{(r-1)! \, (x-r)!} = r \cdot \frac{x!}{r! \, (x-r)!} = r \binom{x}{r}.$$  Thus
$$\begin{align*} \operatorname{E}[X] &= \sum_{x=20}^\infty x \Pr[X = x] \\
&= \sum_{x=20}^\infty x \binom{x-1}{19} (0.9)^{20} (0.1)^{x-20} \\
&= \frac{20}{0.9} \sum_{x=20}^\infty \binom{(x+1)-1}{21 - 1} (0.9)^{21} (0.1)^{(x+1)-21} \\
&= \frac{200}{9} \sum_{x=21}^\infty \binom{x-1}{21-1} (0.9)^{21} (0.1)^{x-21} \\
&= \frac{200}{9}, \end{align*}$$  where in the last step we recognize the sum as being that of a negative binomial random variable with parameters $r = 21$, $p = 0.9$ over its support, so it has value $1$. In general, we see that for parameters $r$ and $p$, $$\operatorname{E}[X] = \frac{r}{p}$$ for this particular parametrization of the negative binomial distribution.

Comment: I cannot thank you enough for this!